# Check the parameter already in server

Tags: linux, oracle, unix

How to check the already set parameters in Linux/Oracle.

For example, as soon as I login to Linux if I type cd $AU_TOP, it directly goes to the path set in AU_TOP.
Now I want to see like AU_TOP what are the other parameters is there.

Comment: `echo $AU_TOP` or `env` or (if it's exported to sub-processes) `export`... might be worth looking at the man oage for your shell too, or a beginner's guide to Linux.

Comment: Why Down Vote my question ? :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If typing cd $AU_TOP take you to some directory - Means you have set environment variable and you can check all environment variable using below command -

```
printenv
```

Comment: There doesn't seem to be an alias involved in the OP's command? `cd` is a builtin command; AU_TOP is an environment variable. `printenv` is probably a better choice than the `env` I mentioned in a comment though.

Comment: Thanks.. Vipin/Alex